# Response an xml file in modal popup

Tags: c#, asp.net

This code is in control.ascx  and control is put in ModalPopup.aspx page.

First ai try with response.end() - this code throw exception.
After ai try coment this line, but nothing is hapen.

Browser is IE8

```
try
    {
        //export
        StringBuilder sb = ExportToExcelXml();
        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] byteText = encoding.GetBytes(sb.ToString());

        Response.Clear();
        Response.Charset = "utf-8";
        Response.ContentType = "text/xls";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=export.xls");
        Response.BinaryWrite(byteText);
        //Response.End();         
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
```

Comment: i forgot to say, this control when is put in the aspx page NON MODAL POPUP -  work fine

Comment: I am also facing same issue, download not working in Modal popups. Have you found the solution/workaround for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the response has been started, you cannot clear it and change it's content type.  In the case of an .ascx file, you're inside an .aspx file which is probably already started filling out the response.  Can you move this to a .ashx (Generic Handler) instead?